# React native app from another project with same package is not installing when another app is installed

Tags: android, react-native, package, android-package-managers

I have two different react native project folder (0.67.2 & 0.68.2) with same package name.

I am able to install app1 when app2 is not installed and vice-versa.

But when app1 is installed and app2 with higher versionCode and versionName is not installing successfully to replace app1. I am using same keystore file and values.

[image: Screenshot of unsuccessful installation of app2 when app1 is installed]

[image: Error shown by playstore when i uploaded aab file for new prduction release]

Why So? How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture to true in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

Hit Upvote if that solved your problem.